# ImportError: cannot import name namedtuple

Tags: python, importerror

I have a python script that produces the following error when run:

```
import urllib2
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
import httplib
File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 73, in <module>
from urlparse import urlsplit
File "C:\Python27\lib\urlparse.py", line 119, in <module>
from collections import namedtuple
ImportError: cannot import name namedtuple
```

I also use the `openpyxl` package, located in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages, which contains a `collections` folder with a `__init__.py` file. I figured this is what causes the problem, because it may be preventing the python 2.7 collections module from being imported.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the collections package inside the openpyxl or outside?

Comment: Also, have you somehow gotten `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl` to your `sys.path`? If so, that's the problem. (Never add a package directory itself to your path.)

Comment: The collections folder is inside the openpyxl folder. Also, the openpyxl directory is not in my sys.path. I do added it a few days back  with `sys.append` in my script. This was for testing purposes and `print sys.path` doesn't list the openpyxl directory anymore so I think it's not my sys.path.

Comment: I printed the `sys.path` in my IDE (PyDev for Eclipse) now instead of in the command line: It contains directories from every site package I use. I guess this is done by Eclipse when adding an external library in `project-->properties-->PyDev PYTHONPATH`. But without adding them the program doesn't work, how do I fix this?

Comment: Never mind, deleted the openpyxl module from the PYTHONPATH in Eclipse and now working! Thanks

Comment: The reason it worked is when you added `openpyxl` to your path, Python found `collections` there and stopped searching anywhere else. You don't need to add anything `site-packages` to your PYTHONPATH, this directory is searched by default by Python. In fact, in most cases you don't need to modify PYTHONPATH at all.

Answer (score 19):

This can also happen if your local script contains a "collections" module due to the way Python handles relative and absolute imports.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is working in PyCharm, editing the configuration of the run and deselecting "Add source roots to PYTHONPATH" will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but this worked when I changed Collection Package to a simple collection directory.

**I just deleted the **init**.py file from the collections**

this can be due to the package name Collections. this can be also resolved by renaming Collection Package to othername.